# Action in form using phalcon

Tags: phalcon

Hello everyone I am new to phalcon. My question is How do I provide form action??I have created a login page now on click I want to check user name and password..can anybody help me,please?

Comment: Please show us what you tried

Comment: Give us some code and your problems

Answer (score 0):

for example if your action is loginAction inside UserController , it will be like that :

```
<form action="/user/login"></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for some automation regarding urls. This will do the trick:

get("controllerName/actionName") ?>">

$url is a global service available in all views. It uses your routes to create the correct URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Volt then you can do it like this:

`{{ form('controller/action')' }}`

`{{ end_form() }}`

Otherwise its:

`\Phalcon\Tag::form('controller/action');`
`\Phalcon\Tag::endForm();`

If you were meaning that you want to create the code that responds to the form submission then you need to create your loginAction inside your users controller as @jkhaled has pointed out.